# socket.io emit firing three times

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, emit

I'll start by saying I've found several similar issues posted on this site. None of them apply to my situation though.

I have a server and client (as is the norm with node.js/socket.io) and call emit a socket event when a button is pressed. This works fine... Except it seems to emit three times (at least the server runs the function three times). I've been staring at the code for way too long at this point and need another set of eyes.

Hopefully someone has an idea.

client code:

```
importJS('/js/pages/admin_base.js',function(){
    var restartLMC = function(io){
        toggleLoad();
        var user = localStorage.getItem('User');
        io.emit('restart_request',{session: user});
    };
    AdminIO = new io('http://localhost:26266');
    AdminIO.on('restart_success',function(dat){
        toggleLoad();
        dropInfo(dat);
    });
    AdminIO.on('sendError',function(dat){
        dropInfo(dat,{level: 'error'});
    });
    AdminIO.on('restart_fail',function(dat){
        toggleLoad();
        dropInfo(dat,{level: 'error'});
    });
    $('#restart').on('click',function(){
        restartLMC(AdminIO);
    });
});
```

Admin code:

```
process.stdout.write('\033c');
console.log('\x1b[36m', "Admin server starting...", '\x1b[0m');
var 
    ini = require('node-ini')
    , conf = ini.parseSync('../config.ini')
    , CS = require('../lm_modules/CoreSync.js')
    , CoreSync = new CS()
    , checkSession = function (session, callback) {
            var res;
            if (!CoreSync) { throw "Fatal error, there is no connection to the Core service!"; }
            if (CoreSync.sessions) {
                if (CoreSync.sessions[session]) {
                    res = CoreSync.sessions[session];
                    callback(res);
                }
                else {
                    CoreSync.sync('session', function (err, dat) {
                        if (CoreSync.sessions[session]) {
                            res = CoreSync.sessions[session];
                            callback(res);
                        } else { res = false; callback(res); }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                res = false; callback(res);
            }
            if (res === "undefined") { callback(false); }
        }
    , runCMD = function(cmd,errCB,callback){
        var
            command
            , args;
        if(cmd.cmd){ command = cmd.cmd; } else { command = cmd; }
        if(cmd.args){ args = cmd.args; }
        const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;        
        const ex = spawn(command, args);
        ex.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            callback(data);
        });
        ex.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            errCB(data);
        });
        ex.on('close', (code) => {

        });
    }    
    , executeCMD = function(cmd,callback){
        const exec = require('child_process').exec
              , cdw = (__dirname + '/../');
        exec(cmd, {cwd: cdw}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                callback(err,null);
                return;
            }
            callback(stderr,stdout);
        });
    }    
    , io = require('socket.io').listen(26266) // can use up to 26485

console.log('\x1b[32m', "Admin server started.", '\x1b[0m');
console.log("Admin server listening at " + "http://" + conf["Server"]["binding"] + ":26266");
io.on('connection', function (socket) {   
    socket.on('restart_request', function(req){
        console.log('Recieved restart request');       
        var success = false
            , session = JSON.parse(req.session)
            , sessionID = session.sessionID;
        checkSession(sessionID, function (ses) {
            if (ses === false) { console.error('CheckSession failed: No session exists'); return; }
            if (ses.user.uuid !== session.uuid) { console.error('CheckSession failed: UUID mismatched'); return; }
            if (ses.user.role < conf['Permissions']['lm_restart']){ socket.emit('restart_fail','Insufficient permissions.'); return; }
            if(process.platform === 'win32'){            
                executeCMD('cd',function(err,res){
                    var errSent = false;
                    if(err){                        
                        console.error(err);
                        if(!errSent){ socket.emit('sendError','Restart failed'); }
                        errSent = true;
                        if(res === null){return;}
                    }
                    console.log(res);
                    socket.emit('restart_success','LM successfully restarted.');
                });                
            }
            else if(process.platform === 'linux'){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who may have seen this and found it a curious question/situation... I found two parts to this.

The first part is the $().on binding. For some reason (even though it's by no means called multiple times in the js code) adding unbind() in front of the binding resolved the issue in part... it cut the extra emits down from 3 to two (until I started another server app, then it went back up to three...)

The other part I found was that (for some reason) the socket.io connection is being duplicated as many times as there are socket servers running. More details on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312940/socket-io-multiple-connections)... I believe that once the cause for this is found, my issue will be resolved.