# Socket.io multiple connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Strange issue I haven't really found documentation about. I think it may end up being a simple case of "you don't understand how the product works" and I'm hoping someone can fill the gap(s).

Here's what's going on... I have 3 separate apps which are socket.io servers. They're all listening on different ports. Each server is intended for a different specialized purpose. I'm building the application so that I can expand it in parts and only impact the individual isolated pieces I need to change/update.

This was working fine, until I realized that for each application running there's an extra socket connection *per server*. So if I have 3 apps, then I have 3 connections on each server.

The evidence of this is that if I add a console.log("Connected") to each server then connect a client, each server reports as many connections as there are servers. Hopefully this makes sense.

My goal, is I want 1 connection per server. It seems like the connections are each acting as a generic connection to all socket servers. My server listeners are set up like this :

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(26265) // can use up to 26485
```

My clients connect like this :

```
socket = new io('http://localhost:26265')
```

EDIT:

To add on to my original question so that you can see more code...

Full client code:

```
importJS('/js/pages/admin_base.js',function(){     
        AdminIO = new io('http://localhost:26266');
        AdminIO.on('send_users',function(rows){
            toggleLoad();
            /*
            if(typeof rows === 'object'){
                rows = Array(rows);
            }   
            */  
            appendUsers(rows);       
            console.log(rows);
        });
        AdminIO.on('failed_users',function(){
            toggleLoad();
            dropInfo("Failed to retrieve userlist",{level: "error"});
        });
        AdminIO.on('test',function (q) {
            console.log(q);
        });
    queryUsers(AdminIO);
});
```

The server code is pretty long... So the relevant pieces are :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(26266); // can use up to 26484
//.... imported additional modules and defined simple functions here
io.on('connection', function (socket) {  
    socket.on('restart_request', function(req){
        var success = false
            , session = JSON.parse(req.session)
            , sessionID = session.sessionID;
        checkSession(sessionID, function (ses) {
            if (ses === false) { console.error('CheckSession failed: No session exists'); return; }
            if (ses.user.uuid !== session.uuid) { console.error('CheckSession failed: UUID mismatched'); return; }
            if (ses.user.role < conf['Permissions']['lm_restart']){ socket.emit('restart_fail','Insufficient permissions.'); return; }
            if(process.platform === 'win32'){            
                executeCMD('START "" .\\windows\\scripts\\restart_lm.bat',function(err,res){
                    var errSent = false;
                    if(err){                        
                        console.error(err);
                        if(!errSent){ socket.emit('restart_fail','Restart failed'); }
                        errSent = true;
                        if(res === null){return;}
                    }
                    console.log(res);
                    socket.emit('restart_success','LM successfully restarted.');
                });                
            }
            else if(process.platform === 'linux'){

            }
        });
    });
    socket.on('get_users',function(req){
          var success = false
            , session = JSON.parse(req.session)
            , opts = req.opts || null
            , sessionID = session.sessionID
            , col = opts.col || null
            , where = opts.where || null
            , range = opts.range || null
            ;
        checkSession(sessionID, function (ses) {
            if (!ses) { console.error('CheckSession failed: No session exists'); return; }
            if (ses.user.uuid !== session.uuid) { console.error('CheckSession failed: UUID mismatched'); return; }
            if (ses.user.role < conf['Permissions']['lm_user_query']){ socket.emit('userQuery_fail','Insufficient permissions.'); return; }            
            Query.users({col: col, where: where, range: range},function(err,res){
                if(!err){socket.emit('send_users',res);}
                else {socket.emit('failed_users',true);} 
            });            
        });
    });
    socket.on('test',function(q){
        socket.emit('test',q);
    });
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with multiple connections?

Comment: If it was just multiple connections it wouldn't be a problem. The issue is that with multiple connections all .emit() commands are run multiple times. Which means a lot of wasted time/network resources

Comment: Sounds like you're emitting either to the wrong things or in the wrong places.

Comment: You need to show us more of your code because what you've shown does not create multiple connections unless that code is in multiple places in the page.

Comment: I've added some more code as @jfriend00 requested. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Try removing the 'new' keyword from the io thing.
You shouldn't use 'new' there since it would make new instances every time you reload the page or a new client connects.
So, it should look like:
Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(26265);
```

Client side:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:26265');
```

I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give that a shot when I get back to work on it. Thanks!

Comment: That's completely wrong.  That's the client connecting; it needs an instance.  And that will either fail or not make any difference.

Comment: According to socket.io, not wrong I think. Socket.IO transfers all its data using 1 websocket. So, no need to create an instance per client. Anyways you know better than me as I'm still learning and that snippet works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks for the idea KAKAN. I tried it out without defining a new object. unfortunately all this appears to accomplish is re-defining the session each time the socket is built. The "new" keyword allows a new 'copy' of the  function to be built, along with its prototype. So that didn't work, thanks for the thought though!